# Is there a way to sort a list of numbers whilst maintaining their original indexes in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting

I need to sort a list of numbers but I need to keep their initial indexes.

I had previously just created an array of the numbers and then another array of the indexes which I sorted at the same time like so:

```
Dim AverageSuccess(23) As Decimal
Dim intervalList() As Integer = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23}
            x = 2
            Do
                  Sorted = True
                  For i = 23 To x Step -1
                        If AverageSuccess(i) < AverageSuccess(i - 1) Then

                              TempNum = AverageSuccess(i)
                              AverageSuccess(i) = AverageSuccess(i - 1)
                              AverageSuccess(i - 1) = TempNum
                              TempIndex = intervalList(i)
                              intervalList(i) = intervalList(i - 1)
                              intervalList(i - 1) = TempIndex
                              Sorted = False
                        End If
                  Next
                  x += 1
            Loop Until Sorted
```

however this is for a project and my teacher informed me that this is bad programming practise and I should be using a list instead.

I have struggled to find a simple example of how to use a list in VB.net for this purpose, so if someone could give me an example I would appreciate it.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_arraylist.htm

Comment: @Tarik The ArrayList was obsolete about 20 years ago.

Comment: Yes, use List<Integer> as implicitly suggested by @AndrewMorton

Comment: Similar to VB.net https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1

Comment: I have a question: why do you want to keep track of indexes.

Comment: You could create a `CUSTOM CLASS` that holds the decimal value and the original index, then make that class Implement `IComparable`.  Now just call `Sort()` against your `List(Of CustomClass)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how much you have covered about lists in class...

Let us create a list with some integers in:

```
Dim nums As New List(Of Integer) From {9, 8, 4, 5}
```

Now, we want to store the original indices of those numbers. We can do that with the [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) method, which has an optional parameter that will give the index of the current item, and create a new entity with items which we can give names to, say "Num" and "Idx":

```
Dim numsWithIndex = nums.Select(Function(n, i) New With {.Num = n, .Idx = i})
```

Then we can use the LINQ method [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) to get those entities in the desired order:

```
Dim sortedNums = numsWithIndex.OrderBy(Function(nwi) nwi.Num)
```

And we can have a look at what we have constructed with

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, sortedNums))
```

which outputs:

```
{ Num = 4, Idx = 2 }
{ Num = 5, Idx = 3 }
{ Num = 8, Idx = 1 }
{ Num = 9, Idx = 0 }
```

(It shows the names we gave to the properties of the anonymous type created with `New` earlier.)

Here is the whole thing as a console app you can copy-and-paste to investigate with on your computer:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim nums As New List(Of Integer) From {9, 8, 4, 5}
        Dim numsWithIndex = nums.Select(Function(n, i) New With {.Num = n, .Idx = i})
        Dim sortedNums = numsWithIndex.OrderBy(Function(nwi) nwi.Num)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, sortedNums))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Hi! Just a follow up question - I need to get just the indexes as an integer for the first 10 items in the sorted list - do you know if there's a function I can use to get just the indexes? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Katie Something like `Dim firstTen = sortedNums.Take(10).Select(Function(x) x.Idx)`.